# Laravel join using query builder as an Object

Tags: php, sql, laravel, laravel-6.2

in my controller i am getting a list with join like  below

```
[
        {
            // transaction table
            "id": 1,
            "remark": "User Creation",
            "amount": 500000,
            "transaction_id": 158936526598058974,
            "user_id": 14,
            "role_id": 2,
            "beneficiary_id": 1,
            "parent_id": 0,
            "created_by": 1,
            "type": 1,

            // user table ( join with beneficiary_id)
            "username": "super_admin",
            "name": "test1",
        },
        {
            //Same
        }
    ]
```

I want to make it as below like eloquent `hasOne()`

```
[
        {
            // transaction table
            "id": 1,
            "remark": "User Creation",
            "amount": 500000,
            "transaction_id": 158936526598058974,
            "user": {  // join users table using user_id
               "username": "admin",
               "name": "test2",
             },
            "role_id": 2,
            "beneficiary": {   //join with users table using be beneficiary_id
               "username": "super_admin",
               "name": "test 1",
             },
            "parent_id": 0,
            "created_by": 1,
            "type": 1,
        },
        {
            //Same
        }
]
```

The question is i know how to do it with eloquent. And i dont know is it possible or not and want to do it using query builder because i don't have a model..

and the join will be in same (users) table for the beneficiary_id and the user_id .. I want to make it as object

My Controller Code Here:

```
$user = User::where('id', $id)->first();
$tablename = Roles::where('id', $user->role)->first();
$name = str_replace(' ', '_', trim($tablename->name));
$transaction = DB::table($name.'_user_transactions')
                  ->where('user_id', $id)
                  ->join('users', 'users.id' , '=' , 'beneficiary_id')
                  ->get();
```

Help needed Thank you!

Comment: So you want to serialise a list of transactions into JSON so that it includes beneficiary and user info?

Comment: actually the `beneficiary_id` is who is doing  the transaction and i want get the user object by the id related to `user.id`

Comment: is it possible by query builder ??

Answer (score 0):

You need to define 2 relations in your `Transaction` model and eager-load them:

```
class Transaction extends Model
{
    protected $with = ['user', 'beneficiary'];

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(User::class);
    }

    public function beneficiary()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(User::class, 'beneficiary_id');
    }
}
```

Then you need to tweak what fields will be visible when serialising. Add into `Transaction` class:

```
$visible = ['id', 'remark', ..., 'user', 'beneficiary'];
```

For `User` you need to make visible only 2 fields `username` and `name`. You can do it by defining `$visible` in `User` model. Or dynamically before serialising the transactions:

```
$transactions = Transaction::all(); //<- here should be your logic for fetching transactions
$transactions->each(function(Transaction $transaction) {
    $transaction->user->setVisible(['username', 'name']);
    $transaction->beneficiary->setVisible(['username', 'name']);
});
```

Then you just need to serialise the transactions:

```
$transactions->toArray();
```

or

```
$transactions->toJson();
```

Comment: well bro if you see my code the tablename is come dynamically based on the role name! So in this case i don't have a model .. either i have to use query builder or raw sql to join them

Comment: thats my main problem! in this case i am creating tables based on user input role_name.. so i can't create those model and define the relations

Comment: you can create an abstract Transaction class and one class per each transactions table and specify table name in there. For example: `class CustomerTransaction extends Transaction { protected $table = 'customer_user_transactions; ... }`

Comment: thats a solution but i cant keep that  `protected $table = 'customer_user_transactions` as static have to use the table dynamically